# What is the reasoning behind the ranking of this ElasticSearch query?

Tags: lucene, indexing, elasticsearch

I have two documents:

```
{
    id: 7,
    title: 'Wet',
    description: 'asdfasdfasdf'
}

{
    id: 6
    title: 'Wet wet',
    description: 'asdfasdfasdf'
}
```

They are almost identical except for the extra word in the 2nd document.

My query is this:

```
var qobject = {
        query:{
            custom_score:{
                query:{
                   multi_match:{
                     query: q, //I searched for "wet"
                     fields: ['title','description'],
                   }
                },
                script: '_score '
            }
        }
    }
```

OK, so when I run this query I get these results:

```
{ total: 2,
  max_score: 1.8472979,
  hits: 
   [ { _index: 'products',
       _type: 'products',
       _id: '7',
       _score: 1.9808292,
       _source: [Object] },
     { _index: 'products',
       _type: 'products',
       _id: '6',
       _score:  1.7508222,
       _source: [Object] } ] }
```

How come id 7 is ranked higher than id 6? What is the reasoning behind the score? Shouldn't 6 be ranked higher because it has 2 words?

**What if I want more words = more weights? What do I do to my query to modify that?**

Explain is below:

```
"_explanation": {
            "value": 1.9808292,
            "description": "custom score, product of:",
            "details": [
                {
                    "value": 1.9808292,
                    "description": "script score function: composed of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 1.9808292,
                            "description": "fieldWeight(title:wet in 0), product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "description": "tf(termFreq(title:wet)=1)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 1.9808292,
                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=8)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(field=title, doc=0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "value": 1,
                    "description": "queryBoost"
                }
            ]
        }

"_explanation": {
            "value": 1.7508222,
            "description": "custom score, product of:",
            "details": [
                {
                    "value": 1.7508222,
                    "description": "script score function: composed of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 1.7508222,
                            "description": "fieldWeight(title:wet in 0), product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 1.4142135,
                                    "description": "tf(termFreq(title:wet)=2)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 1.9808292,
                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=8)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.625,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(field=title, doc=0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "value": 1,
                    "description": "queryBoost"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to achieve with your custom score query? Also, you missed the most important bit in your question: the terms you are searching for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the explain output of your query to know why. You can either use the [explain api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/explain/) or add [`"explain": true`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/explain) to your current search request.

By default lucene uses the tf/idf (term frequency, inverted document frequency) similarity to score documents. Different factors are taken into account, for each term that matches the query. The following are the most important ones:

- Term frequency: how frequent the term is within the document. The more the better. If a term appears multiple times the document is a better match.
- Inverted document frequency: how frequent the term is across the index. The less the better. Rare terms win against common terms.
- Norms: index time boosting (default 1, no boost) + field norm, which defines that shorter fields are better than long ones.

Based on the query you're executing, the documents are scored differently because of norms. You can disable norms in your mapping (and reindex), but that way you'll also lose index time boosting (which I don't think you're using anyway). In fact in your example the second document is scored lower because of the lower field norm, despite of the higher term frequency (2 instead of one).

Antoher solution would be to plug in a different lucene similarity: lucene 4 provides more similiraties, and allows also to define the similarity per field. Those features have been exposed in elasticsearch 0.90.

Comment: Thanks Javanna. I've edited my question to include explain and my query ("wet").  Can you take a look at my explain query? How is the final score calculated...is it averaged among the details?

Comment: I guess the reason the document with two words is LOWER than the one with one word is because:  "value": 0.625,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(field=title, doc=0)"...what exactly is the benefit of normss?

Comment: Yep. The second document gets a higher tf, since it contains the term twice, but on the other hand the field has a lower norm (0.625 instead of one) which affects the score too, even more than the tf. The field norm should be something like: `1/sqrt(number of terms)`.

Comment: Do you recommend that I turn norms off? (or is this just a bad example?)

Comment: Well, you should probably try with more real data and see if norms still bother you. In that case yes, you can disable it. Then the length of the fields doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Can norms be disabled at query time? (can i stick it in the query object?)

Comment: YOu're welcome. The field norm is computed while indexing based on the similarity, and stored within the index. You have to reindex, unless you want to plug in a different similarity that doesn't take into account the field norm (I guess you have to write code for it).