# Simple explanation of different ElasticSearch similarity algorithms

Tags: algorithm, search, lucene, elasticsearch, scoring

I am looking into the different similarity algorithms which define how the score of each document is computed during search. The available algorithms are listed here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

My problem is that I have problems to understand them when digging through the wikipedia articles or the class descriptions in the lucene API documentation. I really like the answer about explaining the TF/IDF similarity algorithm (the default in ElasticSearch) here: [What is the reasoning behind the ranking of this ElasticSearch query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699134/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-ranking-of-this-elasticsearch-query) (so this one I understand to a certain amount).

Can somebody provide similiar simple explanations to the other algorithms outlined there? These include:

- bm25 similarity
- drf similarity
- ib similarity

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you run into here, is by the description set forward in the linked answer, Lucene's default similarity, and bm25 are fundamentally identical, in that they both factor in:

- more occurrences in the document are preferred
- terms rarer in the corpus are preferred
- shorter documents are more heavily weighted
- other functions used to adjust score, boosts, etc.

`dfr` actually encompasses 7 different base-models alone, each using a different scoring algorithm, followed by two highly configurable normalization steps.  A number of configuration options fit the very general steps above, some diverge from it.

Similarly, `ib` allows some significant configuration as well, but generally hits the same high points, of favoring higher term frequency, favoring matches on terms that are more rare (by some description), and adjusting for document length, boosts, and other possible normalizations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I assumed already that they are similiar. I guess the complexity of `dfr` & `ib` (compared with the standard TF/IDF) makes it harder to explain it. I am still looking for a more detailed description though. What I am wondering if certain ways the data is modelled in ElasticSearch is more beneficial with one or the other similarity algorithm used.

Comment: As far as Lucene vs ElasticSearch having an impact on which Similarity implementation is better, should be a non-issue.  The same text indexed with the same analyzer searches and scores pretty much the same way in ElasticSearch and raw Lucene.  The default should be used if unless you have a reason to move away from it, generally.  BM25, as noted, may work better for short fields than the Lucene standard.  DFR and IB are very similar to each other (documentation notes they may be merged together later) and provide a lot of options to consider based directly on IR theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment for clarification. I accept your answer.